# pandoc handling of newlines when converting from/to docx

Tags: newline, docx, org-mode, pandoc, line-breaks

I am using pandoc to convert between .docx and .org formats so that I can edit them in a plaintext editor like emacs.
 pandoc has a mind of its own regarding linebreaks/newlines.

Converting from .docx to .org:

1. When the .docx document has a newline, pandoc places a double newline.
2. pandoc removes multiple intentional newlines.

**Example:**

test-doc.docx:

---

Line one


Line two
Line three

---

The command:

```
> pandoc -s test-doc.docx -o test-doc.org
```

outputs test-doc.org:

---

Line one

Line two

Line three

---

Converting from .org to .docx:

3. Pandoc removes newlines.

**Example:**

test-doc2.org:

---

Line one and
then line two.

---

The command:

```
> pandoc -s test-doc2.org -o test-doc2.docx
```

outputs test-doc2.docx:

---

Line one and then line two.

---

This behavior is not corrected by using the pandoc --wrap flags.
This behavior is the same for .docx files created with MS Word and Google Docs.
This behavior is the same when converting between .docx and markdown (.md) format.
This is pandoc version 2.10.1 on Windows.
I would like to get newlines to be converted faithfully between .docx and .org formats.
Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: There are no newlines in a .docx document: it's a sequence of paragraphs, so there are probably paragraph separators, but each paragraph can reflow as needed (e.g. when the window width changes). When you convert that to a text format, you may (or may not) split the paragraph into lines (with a single newline) and the paragraph separator is usually two newlines, to provide an empty line between paragraphs.  So in general there is no way to do what you are asking. The best you can do is approximate the appearance of the docx by using `--wrap` and `--columns` - AFAIK of course.

Comment: perhaps https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-empty_paragraphs

Comment: @mb21   --from=docx+empty_paragraphs makes no difference in the test above, although from the documentation it seems like it should.